# reading data from multiple excel sheets with linq to excel (http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I'm trying to read data from a multiple sheet excel file.
The first sheet has column headers. the second sheet does not. and the third one does not have any. I can successfully read from the first sheet.

When i try reading from the sheet without header, the program  throughs an exception.

```
var sheet1_data = from c in excel.Worksheet<Species>("Sheet1") select c; // This works and the question is how do i retreive data from sheet2?
```

I'm currently using this:

```
var Sheet2_data = from b in excel.WorksheetNoHeader("sheet2") select b;
```

When i try and read from sheet2_data, i get the following exception:

> 'sheet2' is not a valid worksheet name. Valid worksheet names are: 'sheet2,sheet3',

Any help will be highly appreciated.

B.

Comment: is it not a simple casing issue... ("Sheet2"), rather than ("sheet2")?? And do these worksheets actually exist on the spreadsheet. CHeck that you have not renamed them slightly. and that the connection string you are using is pointing at the correct file.

Comment: No, i triple checked any casing issues and there should be no connection string issue as i can read the sheet1.

Answer (score 1):

the sheet name can be abstract using GetWorksheetNames() method.

```
    var sheets = excel.GetWorksheetNames();
    foreach(var sheet in sheets)
    {
      var sheetData = from x in excel.Worksheet(sheet) select x;
    }
```